# Browserstack enable debug in ios device

Tags: browserstack

i am trying to debug an angular application in ios device with versions < 15 from browserstack.
When i try to open 'Settings' it keeps disappears.

Comment: Please add some information about what you would want to set in settings. And what is the exact error you want to debug? You can view the console in Browserstack. Copy-Paste from there to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience access to the device Settings application has been restricted for a while on Browserstack.

I did try to check for any updates and could only find this:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/advanced-features/ios-app-settings

I am not sure if this helps. However, would suggest reaching out to their support to see if there are new developments.